# Returning queryset of all a user's debts?

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-managers

I have a django rest api which an android client is connected to. One of the models on the django rest framework api is called `Debt`:

```
class Debt(models.Model):
    paying_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="paying_user")
    receiving_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="reeceiving_user")
    amount = models.FloatField()
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="USD")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    date_incurred = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField()
    payed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    overdue = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Debt"
        verbose_name_plural = "Debts"

    objects = DebtManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.paying_user == self.receiving_user:
            raise ValidationError("Users cannot be in debt with themselves.")
        super(Debt, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In the `DebtManager` I have a function named `all_debt`:

```
def all_debts(self, user):
    ''' Returns a queryset of all a user's debts '''
    all_debt_queryset = ... # What do I write here?
    return all_debt_queryset
```

To retrieve all a user's debts, I would need to get all `Debt` objects where the `paying_user` attribute equals the `user` parameter (current user) and all `Debt` objects where the `receiving_user` attribute equals the `user` parameter.

How do I get a queryset with all a user's debts?

Comment: I would suggest remove `all_debts` function from DebtManager. It is not suited to be a manager's function. Although its better suited for Debt model's function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter and simply return the queryset. I am assuming that you are sending the user object in the method argument.

```
from django.db.models import Q
def all_debts(self, user):
    return self.objects.filter(Q(paying_user=user) | Q(receiving_user=user))
```

Note: I would suggest remove all_debts function from `DebtManager`. It is not suited to be a manager's function. Although its better suited for `Debt` model's function

Comment: Ok, but that only returns the debt objects where the user is the paying_user. What about the other debt objects where the user is the receiving_user?

Comment: You can use or in the filter. I will update the answer